# reading from serial using shellscript

Tags: shell, ubuntu, cat

I have a serial port device that I would like to test using Linux command line.

And if I run the following command from terminal, it gives output

```
cat < /dev/ttyS0 &
```

This command opens the serial port and relays what it reads from it to its stdout.So, I tried it from shell script file but it is not working

```
fName="test.txt";
awk '
BEGIN { RS = "" ; FS = "\n" }
{
     address = '/dev/ttyS0';
     system("cat < " address );
}
END {
    }' "$fName";
```

But it is not working and giving output.How can I listen to communication between a process and a serial port? Thanks

Comment: what do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: stdout in shellscript

Comment: I mean: you've done an `awk` script (not shell) for what exactly? since the simple `cat` command works for you? and also why do you use `sudo` in the script and not from command line?

Comment: awk is used to read data from txt file and cat is not working may be because system is to execute command and return output but no output

Comment: your command `cat < /dev/ttyS0 &` seem not to be stopped. You're serial device is still open!  Don't use `cat` as `ttyS0` will **never** send *`end-of-file`*! You have to use *timeout*!! See my answer!

Answer (score 2):

#### Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) timeouts

I've successfully read something under `dash`, be using `GAWK_READ_TIMEOUT` environment variable:

```
out=`GAWK_READ_TIMEOUT=3000 awk '{print}' </dev/ttyS0 & sleep 1 ; echo foo >/dev/ttyS0`
```

On my terminal, this output:

```
echo "$out"
foo

Password:
```

or

```
echo "$out"

Login incorrect

testhost login:
```

#### Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) timeouts

You could use FD under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) as:

```
exec 5>/dev/ttyS0
exec 6</dev/ttyS0

while read -t .1 -u 6 line;do
    echo $line
  done
```

or, to read unfinished lines:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -t .1 -u 6 -rn 1 char;do
    echo -n "$char"
  done
echo
```

So you could:

```
echo 'root' >&5
while IFS= read -d '' -t .1 -u 6 -rn 1 char;do
    echo -n "$char"
  done
echo 'password is 1234' >&5
while IFS= read -d '' -t .1 -u 6 -rn 1 char;do
    echo -n "$char"
  done
```

... Once done, you could close FD by running:

```
exec 6<&-
exec 5>&-
```

#### Sample [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) poor terminal script

I've logged and test some commands with:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 5>/dev/ttyS0
exec 6</dev/ttyS0

readbuf() {
    while IFS= read -d '' -t .1 -u 6 -rn 1 char;do
    echo -n "$char"
  done
};

while [ "$cmd" != "tquit" ] ;do
    readbuf
    read cmd
    echo >&5 "$cmd"
done
```

Comment: It's a bash script! What version of bash do you use? Do first `read` loop (without -d) work?

Comment: Added `awk` solution

Comment: fName="test.txt";
awk '
BEGIN { RS = "" ; FS = "\n" }
{
     address = '/dev/ttyS0';
     out=`GAWK_READ_TIMEOUT=3000 awk '{print}' </dev/ttyS0 & sleep 1 ; echo foo >/dev/ttyS0`
}
END {
    }' "$fName";

Comment: i tried your suggestion like this but giving me error

Comment: Just run `out=...` in terminal!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128524/discussion-between-bhumi-shah-and-f-hauri).